# Why cant i see the smoke effect?

Tags: mesh

I was following a tutorial on YouTube beginner, and when I added quick smoke and hit play, nothing showed up. 
I tried a bunch of different things but still cannot see smoke.
If its not showing do you think that means my laptop isn't able to support it, or is there something else going on that I'm not doing.

Comment: In rendered or preview?

Comment: If you use Blender 2.82 or newer see tutorials with Mantaflow solver (you need to bake first). Most of the tuts are with previous blender smoke sim.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the Blender Guru video, this is the top comment from user  r19790606:

> If you can't see smoke and fire you probably use new version of
>   blender (2.82). Correct instruction for 2.82:
>
> 1. Add monkey
> 2. select monkey in object mode
> 3. F3 -> add Quick Smoke
> 4. (different to video) select monkey
> 5. choose Physics->Setting->Flow Type : "FIre + Smoke"
> 6. (different to video) select "Smoke Domain" object
> 7. in physics panel click "Bake Data" and wait... (progress in status bar on the bottom)
> 8. after it 's finished click play to start animation.
>
> video: https://youtu.be/XN6ClIdL8yw
>
> ps : default only 50 frames are animated. you can change this in phisics->cache-> Frane End (you have to Resume or Free and Bake again ... see point 7)

Comment: i had the same problem  but I have done all the steps correctly.